# How do I show a line while painting in WPF?

Tags: wpf, paint

I´m working on a paint application in WPF.
I have made a circle, rectangle and line. I call this function after I release the mouse:

```
private void DrawLine()
{
    Line newLine = new Line();

    newLine.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
    newLine.X1 = start.X;
    newLine.Y1 = start.Y - 50;
    newLine.X2 = end.X;
    newLine.Y2 = end.Y - 50;

    Canvas.Children.Add(newLine);
}
```

This shows the line after I've released the mouse, but I want to see the line *before* I release it, not only after. How can I realize this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately we can't provide much help, because you haven't shown us what you actually did. Show us the relevant parts of the code you have right now, and try to explain as precise as possible what it is supposed to do. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this functionality you can make use of MouseDown and MouseMove events of canvas(especially for line).

Follow the below steps.

1. Store the position of mouse down in a Point type variable(Inside MouseDown) that will be your first point (x1,y1).
2. And in MouseMove again the store the movable point inside Point varible(Inside MouseMove),that will be your second point (x2,y2).
3. Assign the first end of line as (x1,y1) and another end as (x2,y2).
4. Add that line on the canvas.

Hope it will solve your problem.